# Puppet Cron Job With Environment Variable and sys.arg

Tags: python, cron, puppet

I am trying to set a cron job using Puppet (3.6) which will require an environment variable to be sourced. It is calling a Python script which expects 3 sys.arg values, a string, year, and month.

My code, which is not working looks like this:

```
  cron { 'availability_report_test':
    user    => 'root',
    hour    => 1,
    minute  => 40,
    command => 'ENV_VAR=/etc/report.ini /opt/script.py namestring $(date +\%Y \%m)',
  }
```

Where `ENV_VAR=/etc/report.ini` should tell the script where to find it's ini file.

And this bit, should pass the current year and month as space delimited `$(date +\%Y \%m)`
I don't know where the errors would get logged to, so I haven't found  any. The cron runs, but it doesn't produce expected result, so I think my command is incorrect.

Comment: How does the command appear in the file under /var/spool/cron? What happens if you copy the command and run it manually? Also, it is worth noting that cron has an environment parameter that you can use to set ENVs: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/cron.html#cron-attribute-environment

Comment: i'll try with environment, but i think it's also a problem with how the date string is getting returned. this will fail if I run it in command line but puppet likes it. `ENV_VAR=/etc/report.ini /opt/script.py namestring $(date +\%Y \%m)` BUT this will work in command line and fail in puppet (note the quotes difference) `ENV_VAR=/etc/report.ini /opt/script.py namestring $(date +"%Y %m")`

Comment: Can you update the question to show the manifest and error for the version that fails in Puppet then? (Use the command that works in the cronjob and it'll be easier to fix the manifest to work correctly.)

Comment: i just gave up and put the commands in it's own .sh file. it was some escaping problem. `#!/bin/bash
export REPORTING_ATHENA_CONFIG_PATH=/etc/report.ini
/opt/script.py  namestring \`date -d 'yesterday' +'%Y %m'\``